# Kibana 7.17.3 - serverBasePath result in 404 Status

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kubernetes-helm, kibana-7

I setup EFK Stack Using Helm Chart and versions of Elasticsearch Kibana and filebeat are 7.17.3

Helm Chart Link:
Installation is success

Able to access kibana UI (When exposed as service type Loadbalancer)

now when trying to access kibana (using existing nginx ingress and changing kibana service to clusterIP ) after setting server.basePath: "/kibana" results in a 404.

```
kibana.yml

server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.port: "5601"
server.basePath: "/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true

kibana-ingress-ssl.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: kibana-ingress
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - admin'
spec:
tls:
- hosts:
- example.com
rules:

host: example.com
http:
paths:
backend:
service:
name: kibana-kibana
port:
number: 80
path: /kibana
pathType: Prefix
```